# Calling/Passing dictionary objects in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a class with many functions. In one function, I want to build a dictionary object and call that function into another function.  Can that dictionary be passed around explicitly?

Here is an example of what I was previously doing:

```
def dict_function(self):
    dictionary = dict()
    dictionary['sky'] = 'blue'
    dictionary['clouds'] = 'white'
    dictionary['grass'] = 'green'
    return dictionary
```

However, until now I have been calling dictionary objects in other functions this way:

```
def process_function(self):
      obj = self.dict_function()
      print obj['sky']
```

Is there a better way to call the variables in the process_function?

Comment: I don't think so; I'd do it in that sort of way.

Comment: How often will you be using the dictionary? If more than once, you might want to set it in the ```__init__``` function and access values like ```self.dictionary['sky']``` to avoid recreation.

Comment: It is only used once and is not static, it is constantly being regenerated, that is the reason why I didn't put it in the __init__ thanks for the insight though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has dictionary literals, which are both faster and much nicer to read than constructing it by setting keys individually.

```
def dict_function(self):
    return {
        'sky': 'blue'
        'clouds': 'white'
        'grass': 'green'
    }
```

As mentioned in the comments, if the dictionary is static like this, there is no reason to have a function, just store the dictionary and access it.

The only reason you would want to recreate the dictionary each time would be if you intend to mutate the dictionary each time you use it, without that affecting future uses. It sounds like your use case, however, just requires you access the dictionary in other functions.

```
class Something:
    def __init__(self):
        self.colours = {
            'sky': 'blue'
            'clouds': 'white'
            'grass': 'green'
        }

    def draw():
        screen.rect(100, 100, 200, 300, self.colours["sky"])
        ...
```

Comment: Though this isn't exactly what I was hoping for in terms of simplicity, I do like that you gave examples that helped to show different ways of doing what I set out to do.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First declare it:

```
self.dictionary = dict()
```

populate it

```
def dict_function(self):
    dictionary['sky'] = 'blue'
    dictionary['clouds'] = 'white'
    dictionary['grass'] = 'green'
    return dictionary
```

Reuse it

```
def process_function(self):
      obj = self.dictionary
      print obj['sky']
```

Comment: shouldn't that be self.dict in dict_function() instead of dictionary?  also, why not just print self.dict['sky'] in process_function?

Comment: @user3614014 then check the answer below might be what you are looking for ?

Comment: Yes and no, I like the answer below and I feel that it is more appropriate for others who might find this topic interesting.  But thank you for attempting to answer my question!